# Need help with $\frac{w-a}{1-\overline{a}w} = \mu\frac{z-a}{1-\overline{a}z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

I have one exercises that i need help.

Let the Möbius transformation $w=T(z)$ defined by

$\frac{w-a}{1-\overline{a}w} = \mu\frac{z-a}{1-\overline{a}z},\mu=e^i\alpha, \lvert a\rvert<1$

1.Put the points whose coordinates are $a$ and $1/a$ in the sphere. Proof that

$\lvert z\rvert<1$ if and only if $\lvert w\rvert<1$

and

$\lvert z\rvert=1$ if and only if $\lvert w\rvert=1$

2.Study how transforms the apolonio circles of focus $a$ and $1 / a$

3.Proof that every Möbius transformation $w=T(z)$ which satisfy the point 1 are of the form

$T(z)=\frac{\alpha z+\beta}{\overline{\beta}z+\overline{\alpha}}, \lvert \alpha\rvert^2=\lvert \beta\rvert^2=1$

Well the first point is excuse me for my english. I have proved that $\phi_a(z)=\frac{z-a}{1-\overline{a}z}$ is a bijection from $\mathbb{D}$ in $\mathbb{D}$ but i cant understand how is the function $w=T(z)$. If someone can help me i will be very gratefull.

Comment: If $\phi_a(w)=\mu\phi_a(z)$ and $\phi_a$ is bijective then $T(z)=\phi_a^{-1}(\mu\phi_a(z))$.

Comment: oh thank you! i didnt understand the exercises in that way, then the point 1 i think that i can do it. Could you tell me something about point 3?

Comment: To answer 3 you need to calculate $T$ explicitly and see if it is in that form.

Comment: thank you, is there aniway to point your answer?